# May I use NSCoder::encodeInteger:forKey: and decodeIntegerForKey: methods with argument of type NSUInteger?

Tags: objective-c, primitive-types, nsinteger, nscoder, nsuinteger

I need to encode and decode property of type `NSUInteger` with `NSCoder`.

Is it safe to use `NSCoder::encodeInteger:forKey:` and `NSCoder::decodeIntegerForKey:` methods for that?

The other way around that comes to my mind is to wrap the unsigned integer into `NSNumber` first. But that means some more code and I do not like it much.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it safe to use NSCoder::encodeInteger:forKey: and
>   NSCoder::decodeIntegerForKey: methods for that?

Yes, it is safe, because all architectures on OS X and iOS use the *two's complement*
for representing signed numbers. For example (assuming a 32-bit architecture), in

```
NSUInteger n = 0xFFFFFFFF;
[aCoder encodeInteger:n forKey:@"n"];
```

`n` is converted to a signed integer with the same memory representation, which is `-1`.

And in

```
 NSUInteger n = [aDecoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"n"];
```

the signed integer `-1` is converted back to an unsigned integer with the same memory representation, so that you get back the original value.

Comment: Does this answer hold true for 64-bit architecture?

Comment: @rmtheis: Yes, I am pretty sure it does (NSUInteger is a 64-bit integer on 64-bit architectures. I just gave an example for 32-bit).